# How should I find the four vertices of a rectangle if I have its center of gravity and it length and width?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, rectangles

basically all I want to know is in the question.
I know that in a square if I have the length of it and its center of gravity I can find the vertices by this formula:
If the coordinates of the center of gravity is G(1, 2) and its length is 3, and suppose the four vertices are A, B, C and D:
XA = 1 - 3/2
YA = 2 - 3/2
Etc...

Comment: Are you assuming the rectangle is aligned with the $x$ and $y$ coordinate axes (and not tilted)?

Comment: Center of gravity for a rectangle is the midpoint so half of it length and width is one side, half on the other.

Comment: A rectangle, an abstract mathematical figure, doesn't have a "center of gravity" it has a "centroid"!

Comment: What are $XA$ and $YA$ and if they are lengths, why is $XA$ negative?

Comment: @ndhanson3, I think XA and YA are supposed to the the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point A that's understood to be the lower lefthand corner of the square.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes it is.

Comment: @P_M, it would help to say so explicitly in the question. It would also help if you explained what you are finding difficult about generalizing from squares to rectangles. (I can imagine one possible point of confusion: "length" and "width" may or may not correspond to the $x$ and $y$ axes in that order. But I can't know if that's a point of confusion for you.)

Comment: @BarryCipra well yes, in the case of a square we only have 1 value for the side, but for the rectangle we have 2 values, 1 for the length and the other for the side.

Comment: @P_M Yes, so what have you tried? I recommend drawing a picture if you have not yet done that.

Comment: @ndhanson3 I did so before asking the question, and I'm still figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you have a rectangle $ABCD$ where

> $AB$ is parallel to $x-$axis
> $|AB| = |CD| = a, |BC| = |AD| = b; a, b \gt 0$
> Coordinates of $G (h, k)$

Then the coordinates of vertices are given by $(h \pm \frac{a}{2}, k \pm \frac{b}{2})$. Going anticlockwise starting from $A$, the signs are $(+, +), (-, +), (-, -) $ and $(+, -)$.

---

Note that the vertices of the rectangle are on a circle with radius $\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}$ with center at $G(h, k)$. If we rotate the rectangle by angle $x$ in anticlockwise direction by point $G$, $A'$ is our new $A$ and coordinates of $A'$ is given by,

$\displaystyle \big(h + \frac{a \cos x - b \sin x}{2}, k + \frac{a \sin x + b \cos x}{2}\big)$

Other vertices follow the same pattern.

Comment: Very helpful and kind from you to explain this much. Thank you.